# Is this taxi fare pricing correct? Ola cabs charging me for x2.8 instead of x1.8

Tags: taxis, bangalore

Below is the pricing details charged for opting for an Ola cab during peak hours in Bangalore.  Is this calculation correct?

- First 4 km:            `₹80.0`
- Rate for 14.18 km:     `₹141.8`
- Free ride time (5 min) `₹0.0`
- Ride time charge for 97.43 min: `₹97.43`
- Peak Pricing charge (1.8x)    `₹255.38`
- Discount  `-₹300.0`
- Total tax `₹15.38`

Now, taking the discount off for our calculation, the total fare comes to about `₹590` (`₹589.85`).

Should the Ride charges `₹141.8` be added to the bill when peak hour charges (x1.8) are applied? (I'm effectively paying x2.8 normal fare)

Comment: Ola Cabs operate with a dynamic peak time surcharge and you are informed about the height of the surcharge when booking the cab. It is not possible for anyone here to know if you actually were. Did you get a different quote when booking the cab? If so, the fare calculation is obviosly incorrect and you should complain.

Comment: Or after actually looking at the numbers, INR 255.38 is only an 80% surcharge. You have been charged 1.8 times the fare and not 2.8 times as you claim.

Comment: This question really should be closed.  Not only is the pretext of the question wrong (there was no overcharge), but it's such a specific question that it's not well suited for SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math is wrong.

The first 4 items added together gives a pre-surcharge price of 319.23.

The "Peak Pricing charge" that was added is 255.38, which is 0.8x of the above 319.23.

Thus you were only charge 1.8x the base rate, not 2.8x as you have claimed.

Comment: Well, I got my answer. Thanks for explaining how it works.